# Data Scraping using VBA From website doesn’t download

Tags: vba

I am trying to download some data from website which starts download upon clicking.
But this code is not working, Can anyone help.

```
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    'Navigate to webpage
    Dim ieURL As String:    ieURL = "http://erldc.org/final-schedule.aspx"
    ie.navigate ieURL
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set htmldoc = ie.document
    Set HTMLInput = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs
        Debug.Print HTMLA.getAttribute("classname"), HTMLA.getAttribute("href"), HTMLA.getAttribute("rel")

        If HTMLA.getAttribute("href") = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Calendar1','6420')" Then

            HTMLA.Click

            Exit For
        End If

    Next HTMLA

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for letting the forum know that.

Comment: @cyboashu Can you help me to download 1 month data.I am not getting the appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

Try pausing the macro for a few seconds, maybe 5 seconds, after the `Do While/Loop` that checks for the `ReadyState`...

```
Dim sngFinish As Single
Dim intPauseTime As Integer

intPauseTime = 5 'in seconds
sngFinish = timer + intPauseTime
Do While timer < sngFinish
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Also, I would suggest that you check the `Busy` state of Internet Explorer, in addition to the `ReadyState`, and add `DoEvents`...

```
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help .For each HtmlA line is throwing runtime error.

Comment: For each HtmlA line is throwing runtime error '424'                                                  My most of the programs throw this error.                                                                And can you visit the link as it is not clicking the date as required or is VBA limited that i can't perform this function and i need to use some other language.

Comment: It looks like you should be assigning your collection of elements to HTMLAs instead of HTMLInput --> `Set HTMLAs = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("a")`.

Comment: Thanks Domenic!!!                                                                                         
It worked.                                                                                                               I need some more guidance I hope you can help.May i know where to reach you.

Comment: I'm not available to respond to individual requests.  However, you can post a separate question in a new thread on StackOverflow for further help.

Comment: Sure,Keep in touch.

Comment: Can you tell me some  book for vba and python.I need to write macros for some problems and Data Scraping.